# Enclose a variable in single quotes in Python

Tags: python

How do I enclose a variable within single quotations in python? It's probably very simple but I can't seem to get it! I need to url-encode the variable `term`. `Term` is entered in a form by a user and is passed to a function where it is url-encoded `term=urllib.quote(term)`. If the user entered "apple computer" as their term, after url-encoding it would be "apple%20comptuer". What I want to do is have the term surrounded by single-quotes before url encoding, so that it will be "'apple computer'" then after url-encoding "%23apple%20computer%23". I need to pass the term to a url and it won't work unless I use this syntax. Any suggestions?

Sample Code:

```
import urllib2
import requests    

def encode():
        import urllib2
        query= avariable #The word this variable= is to be enclosed by single quotes
        query = urllib2.quote(query)
        return dict(query=query)

def results():

    bing = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%(query)s&$top=50&$format=json"
    API_KEY = 'akey'

    r = requests.get(bing % encode(), auth=('', API_KEY))
    return r.json
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are four ways:

1. string concatenation

   ```
   term = urllib.quote("'" + term + "'")
   ```
2. old-style string formatting

   ```
   term = urllib.quote("'%s'" % (term,))
   ```
3. new-style string formatting

   ```
   term = urllib.quote("'{}'".format(term))
   ```
4. f-string style formatting *(python 3.6+)*

   ```
   term = urllib.quote(f"'{term}'")
   ```

Answer (score 11):

You can just use string interpolation:

```
>>> term = "foo"
>>> "'%s'" % term
"'foo'"
```

Answer (score 6):

For those that are coming here while googling something like "python surround string" and are time conscientious *(or just looking for the "best" solution)*.

I was going to add in that there are now [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which for Python 3.6+ environments are way easier to use and *(from what I read)* they say are faster.

```
#f-string approach
term = urllib.parse.quote(f"'{term}'")
```

I decided to do a [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) of each method of "surrounding" a string in python.

```
import timeit

results = {}

results["concat"] = timeit.timeit("\"'\" + 'test' + \"'\"")
results["%s"] = timeit.timeit("\"'%s'\" % ('test',)")
results["format"] = timeit.timeit("\"'{}'\".format('test')")
results["f-string"] = timeit.timeit("f\"'{'test'}'\"") #must me using python 3.6+
results["join"] = timeit.timeit("'test'.join((\"'\", \"'\"))")

for n, t in sorted(results.items(), key = lambda nt: nt[1]):
    print(f"{n}, {t}")
```

Results:

```
concat, 0.009532792959362268
f-string, 0.08994143106974661
join, 0.11005984898656607
%s, 0.15808712202124298
format, 0.2698059631511569
```

*Oddly enough, I'm getting that concatenation is faster than f-string every time I run it, but you can copy and paste to see if your string/use works differently, there may also be a better way to put them into timeit than `\` escaping all the quotes so let me know*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBisIwEIbvfYohS2mCMSDCHoR9EvVQNXWza5LSmR6k5NnrtBHdBQ2ETCbz/fln2it9x7AeR@fb2BGQ89ZRUXQW@wshfMGQHretOMZwrEnsOZ8rTT6k2IlqJ2ABFVmkioM5IdSTLfENV@KEliAzq9Vfqomdf/vjkJg0ueRO/4eXSJ0L51d4M/GZSbNT@PA9EngLPTID7TwaWJvPxVPxJ7rwSi0LmelZyrl1nSegJkMFW4SggcAFQJ6zPcm7pHFkPUql4ddeWfdS@8OphkAb3tvVXm0K4NVyGyQbMYSkYaAk1DjeAA)

Comment: I ran a variation of your test that puts quotes around a string variable instead of a string literal. For example, the concat test is `"val='test';\"'\" + val + \"'\""`. In this case f-string is fastest, and concat actually drops to third place behind join.

Answer (score 3):

```
def wrap_and_encode(x):
    return encode("'%s'" % x)
```

Should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with adding the single quotes after it being url encoded? Or, just adding them before hand in you encode function above?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon some code doing it this way:

```
term = urllib.quote(term.join(("'", "'")))
```

(In this case `join()` uses `term` as a separator to combine all elements that were given in the iterable parameter into one string. Since there are only two elements, they are simply wrapped around one instance of `term`.)

Although it is quite readable, I would still consider it a hack and less readable than other options. Therefore, I recommend the use of string formatting as mentioned by others:

```
term = urllib.quote("'{}'".format(term))
```